# Можно ли создать аккаунт Google Play Console, если мне нет 18 лет?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Предположим, что мне 17 и я хочу опубликовать своё приложение.

Не возникнет трудностей с регистрацией аккаунта разработчика GooglePlay?

Comment: Задай этот вопрос в поддержку google play.

Comment: Недавно создавал аккаунт и дали отказ по причине, что нет 18 лет -_-

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что  явно не по теме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, сам через это проходил 2 года назад, проблем с регистрацией не было.